# makeing datamodel in cassandra db

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, datamodel

i am new in Cassandra db. need help to create data model. i have db in PostgraySQL now i want to switch over to Cassandra (installation completed).

> DB name = Automation
>
> Table = Appliance List Fields = appliance id(auto increment,int),
>   appliance name(varchar), appliance add(boolean)
>
> Table = Appliance Keys Fields = appliance key (varchar), appliance
>   id(foreign key of Appliance List table)

Thank you

Comment: Cassandra has to be modelled based on your query[both read & write] patterns rather considering the schema. Because there is no way you can perform join or use foreign keys or many other SQL features. So, Better list your querying pattern to get a valid answer.

Comment: @Tamil : if you have some basic code of Cassandra. plz give.. cassandra is new for me... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a keyspace named Automation

Then crate 2 column families

```
Appliance List Fields

Appliance Keys Fields
```

Create the columns accordingly

Appliance List Fields will have columns

```
appliance id

appliance name

appliance add
```

P.S. There is no in-built auto-increment in Cassandra . You will need to use counter.

Comment: column families have sub columns or sub column families... and column have only key and value right ?

Comment: This is not a proper data model using cassandra for this usecase

Answer (score 0):

As Karthkit said, you can make the two tables into two column families. The columns are added to the column families as is, each a column. Since there are no foreign keys in Cassandra, you have to decide how to deal with the foreign key. However, another solution is to merge the two into a single column family. You have to deal with the 1 : M due to the foreign key. If the relationship is one-to-few, you can make Appliance List Fields into a column family and promote the Appliance Keys Fields into it. There will be multiple Appliance Key Fields within it. If it is one-to-plenty, create the Appliance Keys Fields as a column family and demote Appliance List Fields into it. In this case, it will be redundantly stored in each Appliance Keys Field.